# Question about ArsClassica codes

Tags: listings, sourcecode

I would to know for what is used the code below (Last lines code) in `arsclassica.sty`. Also I would to know why in `arsclassica-settings` there are some repetitions of `\lstset` is not the same thing put all the options in one `\lstset`? And why, for examples this string: `\lstset{moredelim={[is][\ttfamily]{!?}{?!}}}` is repeated?

---

### Listings code

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily}
\lstset{flexiblecolumns=true}
\lstset{moredelim={[is][\normalfont\itshape]{/*}{*/}}}
\lstset{basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily}
\lstset{flexiblecolumns=false}
\lstset{moredelim={[is][\ttfamily]{!?}{?!}}} 
\lstset{escapeinside={�*}{*�}}
\lstset{firstnumber=last}
\lstset{moredelim={[is][\ttfamily]{!?}{?!}}}
```

---

### Last lines code

```
\def\toc@headingbkORrp{% 
  \def\toc@heading{% 
    \chapter*{\contentsname}% 
    \@mkboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}} 
      {\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}}} 
\@ifclassloaded{scrreprt}{\toc@headingbkORrp}{} 
\@ifclassloaded{scrbook}{\toc@headingbkORrp}{}
```

Comment: @MartinSchröder Schröder You are wrong ! that code is in arsclassica.sty, you can see with your eyes that is in that package ! look at the last seven lines of codes: http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/arsclassica/arsclassica.sty And if you look into the user manual of ArsClassica you can see that isn't commented: http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/arsclassica/ArsClassica.pdf. If you read my question is not about the Listings package, but about the programming style of the settings of listings in ArsClassica.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I was looking for your first lines of code. `%-{`

Comment: @MartinSchröder On purpose, I have write "Last lines code". However does not matter ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second code block defines a macro that if executed sets the heading for the table for contents to be based on `\chapter` rather than `\section`. It then executes that code if the main class is `scrrept` or `scrbook`,

In most key=value setting setups calling the command multiple times or using one command with a comma separated list is a matter of style. The multiple command version makes it easier to comment out some of the settings when debugging perhaps. I would guess the duplicated setting is a harmless cut and paste error while setting up the package.